# Stop Access from interfering with the progressbar

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a class-module in my access application that exports all tables (except the system ones) to an excel file, such that the table names are the worksheet names. Since this takes around 5 seconds I wrapped the export-for-loop in a progressbar. This works without a problem. One problem remains though: It seems that the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet command gives the user the option to terminate the action. This is shown by the access application in the same place where the progressbar resides, which is why my progressbar gets interrupted by some text reading roughly as follows: "if you want to stop press esc". I can not figure out which line of vba prevents this from popping up. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
Dim subTdf As TableDef
Dim subIntStatus As Integer
Dim subIntTableCount As Integer

For Each subTdf In pDbPfandDb.TableDefs
    If Not (Left(subTdf.Name, 4) = "msys" Or Left(subTdf.Name, 4) = "usys") Then
        subIntTableCount = subIntTableCount + 1
    End If
Next

SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "Exportiere Tabellen", subIntTableCount

For Each subTdf In pDbPfandDb.TableDefs
    If Not (Left(subTdf.Name, 4) = "msys" Or Left(subTdf.Name, 4) = "usys") Then
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , subTdf.Name, pStrFilePath & pStrFileName & pStrFileExtension, True, subTdf.Name
        subIntStatus = subIntStatus + 1
        SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, subIntStatus
    End If
Next

SysCmd acSysCmdRemoveMeter
```

[Here is how it should always look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2UZQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this before the loop:

`DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)`

Then Re-enable the Warnings after the loop has complete.

`DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)`

Comment: Thank's for the reply. I tried this before however and unfortunately it doesn't work for me. The message still pops up in the area where the progressbar resides.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of this message?

Comment: I edited the question. I was however only able to capture a screenshot of the progressbar showing my message and not the one showing "press esc...", because that one just goes away to quickly (it pops up for like a millisecond every loop). Just to be clear again: the message is visible only on the progressbar. That's why I guess it's not the same as a warning.

Comment: Please note that set warnings is system wide and very dangerous indeed.